# Subsites in Multisite installation throwing 404 error on wp-admin in IIS 7

Tags: multisite, wp-admin, 404-error, iis

Running into an issue where sub sites of a multisite (fresh installation of 3.9 and no plugins or themes) are throwing 404 error when trying to access the wp-admin section of the sub site. It is running on IIS7.

- http://www.mysite.com/subsite/wp-admin -> Throws 404
- http://www.mysite.com/subsite2/wp-admin -> Throws 404
- http://www.mysite.com/wp-admin -> Works for the main site

When we login through http://www.mysite.com/wp-admin and navigate to the sub site then try to log out it also throws a 404.

Was using the [default web.config](http://lauragentry.com/blog/2010/07/30/how-to-create-a-wordpress-3-0-multisite-network-on-a-windows-server-using-sub-directories/), for the re-write rules. But all the sub sites were throwing 404 errors on the css/js files. So, I altered the re-write rules a bit, which you can see below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="WordPress Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^index\.php$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="None" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="WordPress Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}wp-admin/" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="WordPress Rule 3" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="None" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="WordPress Rule 4" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*)" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url=“{R:2}” />
                </rule>
                <rule name="WordPress Rule 5” stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-comments-post.*)” ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url=“{R:2}” />
                </rule>
                <rule name="WordPress Rule 6” stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:2}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="WordPress Rule 7” stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="." ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Am I missing any other re-write rules or need to change? So the subsites do not throw 404 errors when navigating to the /wp-admin page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured out the issue. It was with the generated "Wordpress Rule 6". It was giving 2 identical regex expressions. Removed the extra regex expression. Also had to remove "Wordpress Rule 5". Renumber the rules and now everything works fine.

Here's the updated `web.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="WordPress Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^index\.php$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="None" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="WordPress Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}wp-admin/" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="WordPress Rule 3" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="None" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="WordPress Rule 4" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*)" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:2}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="WordPress Rule 5" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:2}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="WordPress Rule 6" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="." ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Excellent catch, I had the same issue and your fixes to the code work like a charm. You need to replace the special quotes on lines 22, 24, 26 and 30 though. I submitted the changes for you.